# throttle from lodash in react not working

Tags: reactjs, lodash, throttling

I use the throttle from lodash in this way on mouseMove event to track the mouse position in the div square, but the throttle function that I wrote seems not working. where I am wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import _throttle from "lodash/throttle";

function Throttle() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    clientX: 0,
    clientY: 0
  });
  const update = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    setState({ clientX, clientY });
  };
  const throtteFn = _throttle(update, 1000);
  const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    throtteFn(event);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "10em",
          backgroundColor: "green",
          height: "10em"
        }}
     
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      />
      <div>
        <p>clientX: {state.clientX}</p>
        <p>clientY: {state.clientY}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Throttle;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use usecallback in the throttle function.
For now, throttleFn is constantly being created so it doesn't work the way you want it to.

```js
const throtteFn = useCallback(_throttle(update, 1000), []);
```

[sandbox live](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-poincare-mvkpi?file=/src/App.js:315-374)

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the position of the rectangle in the viewport. Keep a ref to get the left and top positions of the rectangle.

Try like this

```
  const ref = useRef();

  const update = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    const { top, left } = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    // deduct the left and top offset values before setting the values
    setState({
      clientX: clientX - left >= 0 ? clientX - left : 0,
      clientY: clientY - top >= 0 ? clientY - top : 0
    });
  };

   ...
   ...

     <>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "10em",
          backgroundColor: "green",
          height: "10em"
        }}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        ref={ref}
      />
      ...
      ...
    </>
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-ramanujan-ybbdg?file=/src/App.js)